# Storing Ajax success data into javascript variable to use in other js function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently doing login form and I have database with the username and password. I've already done comparing if username and password is match with that username But I want to display username is not exist when I click the submit button using the variable come from ajax response. I've already done it but the variable is stored inside html tag.

Here is my old code

```
function checkUsn(){
    var usn = document.getElementById("usn").value;
    if(usn){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'checkdata.php',
            data: {
                emp_username: usn,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#status').html(receiveUsn);
                if (response == "OK"){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#status').html("");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want something like this but this code below didn't work

```
function checkUsn(receiveUsn){
    var usn = document.getElementById("usn").value;
    if(usn){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'checkdata.php',
            data: {
                emp_username: usn,
            },
            success: function(response){
                var receiveUsn = response; //I want to use this for other function
                $('#status').html(receiveUsn);
                if (response == "OK"){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#status').html("");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I will use the variable come from ajax on this function

```
function checkall(receivePw, receiveUsn)
{
    if(receiveUsn == "OK" && receivePw == "MATCH"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

php code

```
<?php
include 'db_config.php';
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if(isset($_POST['emp_username'])){
    $usn = $_POST['emp_username'];

    $checkdata = "SELECT emp_username FROM emp_details where emp_username='$usn'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $checkdata);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        echo "OK";
    }else{
        echo "Your Username not exist";
    }
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['emp_pw']) && isset($_POST['emp_usn'])){
    $pw = $_POST['emp_pw'];
    $usn = $_POST['emp_usn'];

    $get_pw = "SELECT emp_password FROM emp_details where emp_username='$usn'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $get_pw);

    //$get_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //echo $get_num_rows;

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    //echo $row["emp_password"];

    // check if password is match with username
    if($pw == $row["emp_password"]){
        echo "MATCH";
    }else{
        echo "Wrong password";
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

login form

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="/login_action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkall();">
    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
      <img class="avatar img-responsive col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" src="img/employee_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="usn"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input id="usn" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="usn" onkeyup="getPw();checkUsn();" required>

      <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input id="pw" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw" onkeyup="getPw();checkUsn();" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
    <span id="status">status</span><br>
    <span id="status2">status</span><br>
    <span id="status3">status</span>
  </form>
```

Please help Thank you!!!

Comment: why don't you call this function in success block. 
`success: function(response){checkall(receivePw, response)`. If you want to access this response with the variable you can create a global variable then use that as argument.

Comment: Thanks for quick response sir urfusion. I will update my question I will include the php code and html form

Comment: Hi sir urfusion how could I achieve to  create a global variable then use as argument? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `<script>` tag you need to declare a variable at the root level, this will create the global variable. It's considered best practice not to pollute the global space so declare an object at the global level and use that to store your global variables.

```
<script>
  var myGlobalContainer = {};
</script>
```

Now in the JavaScript code on the page you can use the `myGlobalContainer` object.

```
 // set a value
 myGlobalContainer.hello = "world";

 // read a value
 console.log(myGlobalContainer.hello);
 // "world"
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass ajax response on that global variable? if so how I would do that? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you sir Dan it works!! It log in console OK and MATCH but I want to one more question. this code not returning true even I put the correct username and password. 

 if(myGlobalContainer.usn == "OK" && myGlobalContainer.pw == "MATCH"){
  return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare your variable 'receiveUsn' at starting of your java script so it will become a global variable .the problem is your have declared  var receiveUsn with in ajax success function so its now a local variable and cant't be used in other function .make it global will solve your problem

Comment: do I need to declare receiveUsn in checkall function parameter so it will access the global variable?

Comment: no just declare the variable outer the checkUsn function and use it anywhere you want

Answer (score 0):

Initialise a variable on top of Javascript:

```
myglobalvariable = '';
```

Now store your ajax input in variable and it's accessible everywhere:

```
......
success: function(response){
    myglobalvariable = response;
    $('#status').html(receiveUsn);
......
```